# How can I change x -- a into x + a when using Defer?

Tags: output-formatting

I have a list

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {{7, 1, -5, 1}, {3, 1, -5, 3}, {5, 1, -3, 1}};
```

and I use `Defer` in `Defer[Log[k, (x - a) (x - b)] == c]`

```
myfun[{k_, a_, b_, c_}] := {Defer[Log[k, (x - a) (x - b)] == c], 
   Reduce[Log[k, (x - a) (x - b)] == c, x, Reals]};
myfun /@ list
```

> {{Log[7, (x - 1) (x - -5)] == 1,
> x == -6 || x == 2}, {Log[3, (x - 1) (x - -5)] == 3,
> x == -8 || x == 4}, {Log[5, (x - 1) (x - -3)] == 1, x == -4 || x == 2}}

I get `(x-- 5)` and `(x - -3)`. How can I get `(x + 5)` and `(x  + 3)` in output?

Comment: try replacing `Defer[Log[k, (x - a) (x - b)] == c]` with `Defer[Log][k, (x - a) (x - b)] == c`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way

```
list = {{7, 1, -5, 1}, {3, 1, -5, 3}, {5, 1, -3, 1}};
myfun[{k_, a_, b_, c_}] := 
 With[{z = (x - a)  (x - b)}, {Defer[Log[k, z] == c], 
   Reduce[Log[k, z] == c, x, Reals]}]
```

Now

```
myfun /@ list
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Inactive`. This way the other arguments will still evaluate.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

list = {{7, 1, -5, 1}, {3, 1, -5, 3}, {5, 1, -3, 1}};
myfun[{k_, a_, b_, c_}] := {Inactive[Log][k, (x - a) (x - b)] == c, 
   Reduce[Log[k, (x - a) (x - b)] == c, x, Reals]};
myfun /@ list 

Activate[%]
```

---

[image]